# Android - String Cannot Cast Boolean SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I have been debugging this problem for awhile and I can't find where I am setting a boolean as a string or whatever. I can show more if needed but let me know if you see anything in my stacktrace.

my stacktrace:

```
08-13 21:25:14.685: D/SensorManager(10583): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41fc5a08
08-13 21:25:14.685: D/Sensors(10583): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
08-13 21:25:14.685: I/Sensors(10583): sendDelay --- 200000000
08-13 21:25:14.685: D/SensorManager(10583): JNI - sendDelay
08-13 21:25:14.685: I/SensorManager(10583): Set normal delay = true
08-13 21:25:14.685: D/SensorManager(10583): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41fd3b80
08-13 21:25:14.700: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:14.700: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:14.700: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:14.720: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:14.720: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:14.745: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:18.870: D/SensorManager(10583): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41fd3b80
08-13 21:25:18.870: D/Sensors(10583): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
08-13 21:25:18.870: I/Sensors(10583): sendDelay --- 200000000
08-13 21:25:18.870: D/SensorManager(10583): JNI - sendDelay
08-13 21:25:18.870: I/SensorManager(10583): Set normal delay = true
08-13 21:25:18.870: D/SensorManager(10583): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41fcc0c8
08-13 21:25:18.890: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:18.890: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:18.890: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:18.915: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:18.915: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:18.940: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:23.970: D/GestureDetector(10583): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
08-13 21:25:23.975: I/System.out(10583): To
08-13 21:25:24.265: D/dalvikvm(10583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 337K, 7% free 12783K/13639K, paused 2ms+13ms, total 26ms
08-13 21:25:25.800: D/dalvikvm(10583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 330K, 7% free 12931K/13831K, paused 2ms+12ms, total 23ms
08-13 21:25:28.900: D/GestureDetector(10583): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
08-13 21:25:29.505: D/GestureDetector(10583): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
08-13 21:25:29.665: D/SensorManager(10583): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41fcc0c8
08-13 21:25:29.665: D/Sensors(10583): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
08-13 21:25:29.665: I/Sensors(10583): sendDelay --- 200000000
08-13 21:25:29.665: D/SensorManager(10583): JNI - sendDelay
08-13 21:25:29.665: I/SensorManager(10583): Set normal delay = true
08-13 21:25:29.760: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:29.760: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:29.760: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10583): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
08-13 21:25:31.010: D/AbsListView(10583): Get MotionRecognitionManager
08-13 21:25:31.690: D/GestureDetector(10583): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
08-13 21:25:31.890: D/AbsListView(10583): Get MotionRecognitionManager
08-13 21:25:31.895: D/AbsListView(10583): Get MotionRecognitionManager
08-13 21:25:31.905: D/AndroidRuntime(10583): Shutting down VM
08-13 21:25:31.905: W/dalvikvm(10583): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413782a0)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jordan.dictation/com.jordan.dictation.Settings_ActivityBH}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
 08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedBoolean(Preference.java:1630)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.onSetInitialValue(TwoStatePreference.java:184)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1315)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1127)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:156)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:97)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:38)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:305)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at com.jordan.dictation.Settings_ActivityAH.onCreate(Settings_ActivityAH.java:20)
 08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5200)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    ... 11 more
08-13 21:25:31.925: D/dalvikvm(10583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 6% free 13073K/13895K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 15ms
08-13 21:25:31.925: D/AbsListView(10583): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
08-13 21:25:31.925: I/MotionRecognitionManager(10583):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@4209b458
08-13 21:25:50.045: I/Process(10583): Sending signal. PID: 10583 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Hey What is at Settings_ActivityAH.java Line 20?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the Line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
08-13 21:25:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10583):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)
```

Looks like,You are saving the value as String in Shared Preferences and reading it back as Boolean which is causing this Exception.

Check what kind of value -String/Boolean is suitable for you and save and read the similar type of value to solve this issue.

Like, as you are saving the String values in Shared Prefrences , read it back as String.
Or if you need to read the value as Boolean ,save it as Boolean instead.

Answer (score 3):

If You've saved 'Shared Preferences' having key to store  or etc, which use 'string' value, then later you used same key for 'CheckBoxPreference' after requirement changed.

In this case, You have to delete sharedPreferences from phone for youur app. Because previously stored value is String and now key is used to store Boolean.

Comment: Great! You saved my weekend ;) I uninstalled the app and after that it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

You must be passing a value in the Shared Prefs and putting it as Boolean type but passing the value as a String. I mean you must be passing true or false like this- "true" , you need to pass it like this- true.